# Does setting Aes KeySize generate a new key?

Tags: system.security

According to Microsoft's [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.symmetricalgorithm.keysize?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Security_Cryptography_SymmetricAlgorithm_KeySize) on System.Security.Cryptography.Aes, the key size can simply be changed by setting the `KeySize` property.

Does changing the key size automatically generate a new random key of the new key size? The documentation is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, or no, depending.

Setting `KeySize` makes the object forget the key. If a new one is provided by setting `Key` no new key was technically generated. But when the object has no key, but needs one, a new key (of size `KeySize`) is created and remembered.

In general, you should either set `KeySize` (to make a random one) or `Key` (which adjusts `KeySizeValue`), not both.